# Integration of LinkedIn API in Django app

Tags: python, django, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get access token from Linkedin API using the python-linkedin package given at **https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin** using following code

```
def get_linkedin_token(request):

    access_code = request.GET.get('code')

    if access_code is None:
    request.session['authentication'] = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(
                LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                RETURN_URL,
                linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
    **url = request.session['authentication'].authorization_url**
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:
        request.session['authentication'].authorization_code = access_code
        access_token = authentication.get_access_token()
        return HttpResponse(access_token)
```

the above code give me an Type error at **url** ' is not JSON serializable'; when I open the url in browser it works fine but in app its giving error described.
what is going wwrong how can I fix it?
thanks in advance

Comment: hi I found my error; I called authentication.get_access_token() instead of request.session[authentication].get_access_token() in second line of else case

Comment: So you found the solution. If you think it is of use to others, then please write a formal answer (with an explanation of why your solution is the solution). If not, then delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

the above code is right the minor correction needed at the line

```
access_token = authentication.get_access_token()
```

it should be

```
access_token = request.session['authentication'].get_access_token()
```

because I initialized authentication object as session variable and was calling simply without using request.session[ ]. So after doing so anyone can easily get access token for LinkedIn API using python-linkedin